# How to route to a laravel controllers method

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm quite new to laravel4 but with some codeigniter background. I try to figure out how do I route with url to a controller method

my url should look like

```
/admin/products{controller_name}/parser{controller_method}
```

than controller

```
<?php namespace App\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Models\Product;
use Image, Input, Notification, Redirect, Sentry, Str;

    class ProductsController extends \BaseController {

        public function index()
        {
            return \View::make('admin.products.index');
        }

            public function parser()
        {
            return \View::make('admin.products.parser');
        }

    }


Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin', 'before' => 'auth.admin'), function()
{

        Route::resource('products',           'App\Controllers\Admin\ProductsController');
        Route::resource('products/parser',    'App\Controllers\Admin\ProductsController@parser');

});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use the `Route::resource` method, you're actually creating many different routes in a single call:

1. GET /admin/products

   - maps to an `index` method on the controller
2. GET /admin/products/create

   - maps to a `create` method on the controller
3. POST /admin/products

   - maps to a `store` method on the controller
4. GET /admin/products/{id}

   - maps to a `show` method on the controller
5. GET /admin/products/{id}/edit

   - maps to an `edit` method on the controller
6. PUT/PATCH /admin/products/{id}

   - maps to an `update` method on the controller
7. DELETE /admin/products/{id}

   - maps to a `destroy` method on the controller

Saying `Route::resource('resource', 'Controller')` is all that you would need to do in order to create *7 different* routes, and is a convenience method really helpful when creating API's.

All that said, I don't think this is what you want to do.  Instead, I think you just want to use the regular `get` and/or `post` methods for this:

```
// Here is a single GET route
Route::get('products', 'App\Controllers\Admin\ProductsController@index');
// Here is a single POST route
Route::post('products/parser', 'App\Controllers\Admin\ProductsController@parser');
```

See more info on Laravel's Resource Controllers in the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers).

As a side note, you can see all of the routes your application is currently aware of by using Artisan's `routes` command:

```
$ php artisan routes
```

You can verify a route is setup correctly by running that command and looking for what method on what controller a given route is being mapped to.